# Char encoding and SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, character-encoding, collation

I have this sql:

> select productid from products where productcode = @code

and @code is a parameter, it's value was `ABCÊ` but it matched `ABC` debugging it in visual studio showed � in the quickwatch. the database has `Latin1_General_CI_AS` as collation. The field type in the database is an nvarchar(50)

So why is the datarow containing productcode = 'ABC' returned when I compare it to `ABCÊ`?
I entered this in my smss `select 1 where 'ABC' = 'ABCÊ'` and it did not return 1, this did: select 1 where 'ABC' = 'ABC'
So is it in my code? something with utf or encoding?

**edit** c# code:

```
SqlCommand comGetProd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ProductID FROM PRODUCTS WHERE (ProductCode = @name)");
comGetProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", "ABCÊ");
```

**edit 15-6-2015**

narrowed the problem down as @Oskar Sjöberg suggested. It is not database related! Because this returns `true`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.csv"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {                  
        Console.WriteLine("D1103SL".Equals(sr.ReadLine()));
    }
}
```

test.csv contains: `D1103SLÊ`

[image]

notepad++:

[image]

so it is http://www.codetable.net/hex/ca I still do not see how it is equal.

Comment: *but it matched ABC debugging it in visual studio showed � in the quickwatch.* What does it means?

Comment: Is the @code parameter nvarchar?  With Unicode literals, you need to specify the `N` prefix to prevent conversion to varchar:  N 'ABCÊ'`

Comment: Please show the code. The `?` appears when you try to convert text from one ASCII codepage to another, never with Unicode text. Most likely, the parameter's type is `varchar`. Also ensure the mangling didn't occur before you even reached the database command, eg reading ASCII input with the wrong codepage

Comment: I used `comGetProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", "ABCÊ");` so I did not specify a sql type. comGetProd is an SqlCommand

Comment: Please show the code that *inserts the value*. That's when the conversion error occurs. Also note that `'ABCÊ'` is a varchar, not Unicode and has to be converted. You need to enter `N'ABCÊ'` to enter nvarchar values. Your `SELECT 1 ... ` statement also compares varchar, not `nvarchar` values, although that doesn't change anything

Comment: I do not insert it. I have inserted `ABC` a long time ago and want to check if `ABCÊ` matches any product.

Comment: @xanatos when I have `ABCÊ` as value for the parameter, the query returns the row containing productcode `ABC` instead of no rows. And the quickwatch shows `ABCÊ` as value for the parameter but displays the (in)famous questionmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently, "\xCA" is a non-breaking space on the Mac — the same as "\xA0" on Windows and in ISO-Latin-1, and " " in HTML.

http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/commentsf6b4-3.html?sid=18447&op=reply&threshold=0&commentsort=0&mode=thread

So when using UTF-8 encoding it just knows that this is a nonsense char and can be skipped, so the strings are equal

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.csv", ASCIIEncoding.UTF8))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D1103SL".Equals(sr.ReadLine()));
    }
}
```

and when using ascii, it 'sees' the Ê and when compared, it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Like below

```
select productid from products where productcode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = @code
```

Comment: Can you explain how/why COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT will fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LINQ, you could use culture comparison.

```
var result = from a in collection.Products
             select a.Productid
             where string.Equals(a.ProductCode, 'ABCÊ', StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: The OP has in issue with conversions, not comparison. In any case, this has nothing to do with LINQ, it's about SQL. LINQ to EF will probably refuse to execute this query, while L2S will load the entire table in memory then try to look for the matching row

Comment: Sorry, I do not use LINQ

Answer (score 0):

I tried to setup the same scenario with the same collation, table and example data and ran this code:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstringgoeshere");
connection.Open();
var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ProductID FROM PRODUCTS WHERE (ProductCode = @name)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", "ABCÊ");
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows);
```

It returns zero rows as expected and changing "ABCÊ" in the code to "ABC" returns one row with the correct data.

I think there is another issue at play here, but you need to include a more complete but still minimal example of your code, database schema and database data.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I will see if I can reproduce it in a separate small project

Comment: I have made a similar test project, but when I hardcode the string, like you did, I got no rows. When I read the exact same string from a csv file (copy paste) I got 1 row (and no clue)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` instead of `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`.  [source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/01/09/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/)

Comment: Why would that help with Unicode (nvarchar) fields? The article you link actually mentions `he rules for nvarchar data sorting/comparisons seem to be identical though ` and in fact warns against this  `Mixing the collations  ... could impact on your performance quite heavily or cause collation conflict errors ... especially if you are using the older SQL collation`